# How to fix this deprecated use of std::allocator?

Tags: c++, c++17, allocator

Here are the key points:

1: This project uses the open-source repository [NanoRT](https://github.com/lighttransport/nanort/blob/master/nanort.h) as a raytracer in a project.

2: This project is compiled under Visual Studio 2019 (C++17)

3: This project is compiled with warnings treated as errors (and this cannot be changed). Adding the define to suppress these warnings did not help.

However, it looks like part of this code does not work in C++17, as it uses something that has become deprecated: (line 133 and 134 in the link I provided)

```
  typedef typename std::allocator<T>::pointer pointer;
  typedef typename std::allocator<T>::size_type size_type;
```

I need to figure out how to approach fixing this. The error suggests using `std::allocator_traits` but I am really unfamiliar with this use of `std::allocator` or `allocator_traits`.

Looking at the source, is this a few-line fix, or is this much more complicated than that and would require restructuring large portions of the code?

It looks like `pointer` is used as the return for `allocate()` and the first argument to `deallocate()`, with `size_type` being used in the same way.

```
  // Actually do the allocation. Use the stack buffer if nobody has used it yet
  // and the size requested fits. Otherwise, fall through to the standard
  // allocator.
  pointer allocate(size_type n, void *hint = 0) {
    if (source_ != NULL && !source_->used_stack_buffer_ &&
        n <= stack_capacity) {
      source_->used_stack_buffer_ = true;
      return source_->stack_buffer();
    } else {
      return std::allocator<T>::allocate(n, hint);
    }
  }

  // Free: when trying to free the stack buffer, just mark it as free. For
  // non-stack-buffer pointers, just fall though to the standard allocator.
  void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n) {
    if (source_ != NULL && p == source_->stack_buffer())
      source_->used_stack_buffer_ = false;
    else
      std::allocator<T>::deallocate(p, n);
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to address this, and one size doesn't fit all.

### The simplest path:

For `std::allocator<T>`, the type `std::size_t` is always the same as `size_type`, and the type `T*` is always the same as `pointer`.  So the easiest thing is to just sub in those types.

### The `std::allocator_traits` path:

These types also exist as nested types of the type `std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<T>>`.  So you can access them like this:

```
std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<T>>::pointer
```

It is common to create type aliases to cut down on the verbosity:

```
using pointer = std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<T>>::pointer;
```

---

Irony:  `allocator<T>::size_type` is "de-deprecated" in C++20.

Comment: If I try replacing 

```typedef typename std::allocator<T>::pointer pointer;``` with 

```using pointer = std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<T>>::pointer;```

I get a large number of errors. Some syntax, but ```allocate()``` states "unknown override specifier```. Is the ```using``` syntax the same as ```typedef typename``` here or does the usage need to change?

Comment: It looks like if I use your approach, but with ```typedef typename``` instead, it works great. Thanks!

Comment: Right.  Sprinkle with `typename` until you get the desired results. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `std::allocator<T>::pointer` with `T*` and `std::allocator<T>::size_type` with `std::size_t`. That is what those deprecated member type aliases are defined as.

> is this a few-line fix, or is this much more complicated than that and would require restructuring large portions of the code?

This seems like a trivial change.

> The error suggests using `std::allocator_traits`

`std::allocator_traits` should be used if the allocator type is templated. That appears to not be the case here, and so using `std::allocator_traits` would be unnecessary.

But if we were to fix the problem in a case where the allocator is templated: Let's say the template argument is `Alloc`. Then you should replace `Alloc::pointer` with `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::pointer` and `Alloc::size_type` with `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::size_type`.

> However, it looks like part of this code does not work in C++17, as it uses something that has become deprecated

Actually, use of deprecated features still works. It should still be fixed though since it will stop working in C++20. `std::allocator<T>::pointer` has been removed in C++20.